# How to set up VS Code to give auto-completion and hints for 3rd party javascript libraries embedded in the web page?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I have a 3rd party library, `numjs`, included on a web page:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nicolaspanel/numjs@0.15.1/dist/numjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="./mycode.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

When I write code in `mycode.js`, using the embedded libraries in the web page, I want auto-completion, function documentation etc. to appear:

```js
var a = nj.array([2,3,4]);
console.log(a);
// blah blah blah
```

There are two ways I have found to do this, but both have draw backs:

**1. Use `nodejs` and some packaging library**

If I install a library using node, VS Code recognizes it from the `node_modules` directory. So I can import it into my `mycode.js` and then hints etc. work.

```js
var nj = require('numjs');
// blah blah blah
```

Drawback: Bundling library. Bundled code obfuscated. Learning a bundling library. I think it's too much work to change the compilation of the code just to get auto-completion.

**2. Manually download/and serve 3rd party libraries**

I can download the libraries to a local `vendor/` directory. In the webpage, I change the source of the library script to `vendor/library.js` on my own server.

```js
import * as nj from './vendor/numjs.js'
// blah blah blah
```

Drawback: Have to host/commit 3rd party library to repository.

**3. Last resort - change imports during run-time**

I do the same as **1, 2**. Use `require/import` statements with node/manually downloaded libraries. But when I am about to run the code, I comment out the import statements because those libraries are already embedded in the html with an external source.

Drawbacks: Too manual.

How do I set up VS Code to get hints and auto-completion with 3rd party javascript libraries? Is there a way to do it without my writing my code for `node` and then compiling it for front-end?